# How to get manfid of SD card from linux?

Tags: linux, driver, sd-card, udev

**Normal case.**
**(SD card <-> SD card socket <-> SDIO <-> Chip)**
Linux will create /dev/mmcblk0p1 and I can get these information below:
/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/manfid
/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/oemid
/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/name

**My case.**
**(SD card <-> SD card socket <-> USB Hub <-> USB Host <-> Chip)**
Extra add a USB Hub that for connecting USB host with SD socket.
The USB hub one side is link a USB socket and a SD socket, and other side is link USB host.
When I plug SD card, linux will auto create /dev/sda.
Final, i find no manfid and oemid and name at below:
/sys/block/sda/device/

So, at my case.
**How to get manfid(and oemid and name) of SD card from linux?**

Linux 3.0.8
udevinfo version 100

Thank you for reading it (my English so poor).

Comment: What does `hdparm -i /dev/sda` report?

Comment: hdparm: ioctl 0x304 failed: Invalid argument
hdparm: HDIO_GET_IDENTITY: Invalid argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can't.

Most USB SD card readers only expose the card as a USB mass storage device. They don't provide any way to pass raw SD commands directly to the card, or to read SD-specific registers such as the ones including the manufacturer ID.

Comment: Thanks, It was an unfortunate message.

Comment: Excuse me, how to check the USB SD card reader no support this feature?
May I will find it at linux file, or I can find it at reader driver?
The worst case is the reader chip no support, then linux side will nothing can do.